# primefaces timepicker not rendering properly

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

everything is working fine except that it is somehow now rendering properly.
im on primefaces 5.3 and primefaces extension 0.7.1

heres a sample pic

[image: time picker]

heres my code

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">            
        <h4>start</h4> 
        <pe:timePicker  value="#{ManageActivities.newDetailsTimeEnd}" mode="popup" /> 
</h:panelGrid>
```

did i miss something in the code? or im missing some libraries?

Comment: Might be a bug related to the PM theme you're using. Analyze it with your browser's web tools. It would help us if you deployed the sample somewhere public.

Comment: Might be a problem with custom CSS... Create a [mcve]

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak tnx ill try that

Comment: @Kukeltje i think your right, bootsrap css is causing it

Comment: Yes, Bootstrap is know for messing things up in other frameworks... Their choice on how to do things is not bad (on the contrary), but it has conflicts. Next time investigate more by creating a [mcve]. The step where you'd remove custom css would solve it and you would have more info... reducing code is the step to take!